# Passing arrays through checkbox input values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet, lodash

I am trying to get the intersection of two arrays when the user selects them but I don't know how to pass an entire array through  an input value.
Here is my script:

```
var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.leaflet-control-layers-selector:checked').value;

    result = _.intersection(checkedValue);
    console.log(checkedValue);

document.getElementById("AllMuseums").value = AllMuseums;
document.getElementById("MPaid").value = MPaid;
document.getElementById("MFree").value = MFree;
document.getElementById("MResto").value = MResto;
```

Here are my inputs:

```
<label>
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" id="AllMuseums" checked><span>All Museums</span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" id="MPaid" value="MPaid"><span id="icons1">Paid Admission</span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" id="MFree" value="MFree"><span id="icons2">Free Admission</span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" id="MResto" value="MResto"><span id="icons3">Restaurants</span></div>
    </label>
```

And here are my arrays:

```
var AllMuseums=[Naturhistoriska,Junibacken,ArkDes,Fjarilshuset,Tekniska,Polismuseet,Skansen,Bergrummet,Vikingaliv,Vasa,Nordiska,Nobel,Moderna],
        MPaid=[Junibacken,Fjarilshuset,Tekniska,Polismuseet,Skansen,Bergrummet,Vikingaliv,Vasa,Nordiska,Nobel],
        MFree=[Naturhistoriska,ArkDes,Moderna],
        MResto=[Naturhistoriska,Junibacken,ArkDes,Fjarilshuset,Tekniska,Skansen,Bergrummet,Vikingaliv,Vasa,Nordiska,Nobel,Moderna],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a solution : https://jsfiddle.net/ajxeyqo4

inputs :

first input tag add value

```
 <label>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" id="AllMuseums" value="AllMuseums" checked><span>All Museums</span></div>
</label>
<label>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" id="MPaid" value="MPaid"><span id="icons1">Paid Admission</span></div>
</label>
<label>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" id="MFree" value="MFree"><span id="icons2">Free Admission</span></div>
</label>
<label>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" id="MResto" value="MResto"><span id="icons3">Restaurants</span></div>
</label>
<button onclick='test()'>
    test
</button>
```

And your scripts :

```
function test(){
    var AllMuseums=['Naturhistoriska','Junibacken','ArkDes','Fjarilshuset','Tekniska','Polismuseet','Skansen','Bergrummet','Vikingaliv','Vasa','Nordiska','Nobel','Moderna'],
            MPaid=['Junibacken','Fjarilshuset','Tekniska','Polismuseet','Skansen','Bergrummet','Vikingaliv','Vasa','Nordiska','Nobel'],
            MFree=['Naturhistoriska','ArkDes','Moderna'],
            MResto=['Naturhistoriska','Junibacken','ArkDes','Fjarilshuset','Tekniska','Skansen','Bergrummet','Vikingaliv','Vasa','Nordiska','Nobel','Moderna'];
            
    var checkedValue = document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-control-layers-selector:checked');

    var a =[]
    _.map(checkedValue, function(value) {
        a.push(eval(value.value));
    });

    var result = _.intersection(...a);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. It still just returns the name of my variable  (i.e. MResto) and not an array.

Comment: EDIT, this does work but I get back far more detail in the results than I need. I just need the strings in my arrays. Why is it sending so much more info?

Comment: It's return intersection of arrays that exactly you need.

Comment: It's returning something called node and it contains far more confusing information than some array of strings.

Comment: try this one : console.log(JSON.stringify(result))

Comment: I tried that. Here is my far more detailed fiddle in code pen: https://codepen.io/Arrakis_Surfer/pen/WNwZbME

Comment: Change your function code :

function filter(){
  
var checkedValue = document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-control-layers-selector:checked');
var a =[];
_.map(checkedValue, function(value) {
  a.push(eval(value.value));
});
var result = _.intersection(...a);
console.log(result)
}

Comment: AllMuseums=[Naturhistoriska,Junibacken,ArkDes,Fjarilshuset,Tekniska,Polismuseet,Skansen,Bergrummet,Vikingaliv,Vasa,Nordiska,Nobel,Moderna] ----
You not written as string ---- it should be ---AllMuseums=['Naturhistoriska','Junibacken','ArkDes',.....]